# Limit access to endpoint of WCF service hosted in IIS

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

I'm hosting a WCF service in IIS 7.5. The service has one endpoint with `webHttpBinding`, and one endpoint with `netTcpBinding`. How can I limit access to the nettcp endpoint, so that only local clients (clients running on the same machine) has access? Is it enough to just set the base address to localhost-something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will suggest to use [NetNamedPipeBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx) which is meant for on-machine communication only.

Regarding limiting access to tcp binding, I guess you can use [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx) to limit the access. For example, see [this code-project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFIPfilter.aspx) that has use it for IP Address based filtering - configuring it for local IP (127.0.0.1) should get exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Ah, forgot about that binding. Thank you for the example code, it might come in handy, since I might want to give remote clients access in the future.